# Inheriting the type arguments of the child class function from the parent class function typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, class

I have two typescript classes, one of which inherits from the other

Inside the parent class, a signature index is defined that has a function in its value

The types of the signature index value function arguments are not defined in the child class

```js
class Parent {

    [key: Uppercase<string>]: (
        a: string,
        b: string
    ) => string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    GET(a, b) {   // Parameters implicitly has an 'any' type ❌

        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

By defining the argument types in the signature index function of the parent class, there is no need to redefine the types in the child function.

**bad**

```js
class Parent {

    [key: Uppercase<string>]: (
        a: string,
        b: string
    ) => string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    GET(a:string, b:string) {   // no redefine ❌

        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

**good**

```js
class Parent {

    [key: Uppercase<string>]: (
        a: string,
        b: string
    ) => string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    GET(a, b) {   

        console.log(typeof a) // string ✅ 
        console.log(typeof b) // string ✅ 

        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a missing feature of TypeScript; see the feature request at [ms/TS#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?